# Added a free app from SharePoint Store and don't know how to remove it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

I have followed this msdn link, but it's not what I'm looking for.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx

I downloaded an app from the SharePoint Store and now I want to remove this free, downloaded app from the app gallery.

More info: it's a test environment. I need the app not to appear in the apps gallery when users click "Add an app".

Answer (score 1):

(left menu) `Site Contents`, then select `add an app`

(left menu) `Manage Licenses`, then select the app

(dropdown) `Actions`, then select `Remove this license`

Comment: Did this, it did not remove the app.